# React.js component re-renders child component when it shouldn't

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, rerender

I have a star animation with rocket and a multiplier that gets changed. When the multiplier get's changed it also rerenders the stars even tho the multiplier doesn't effect them in any way. That's my parent component

The variables

```
const starSpeed = {
    'slow': 1,
    'medium': 0.7,
    'fast': 0.2,
  }
  const {money, setMoney} = useContext(MoneyContext);
  const [multiplier, setMultiplier] = useState(1.00);
  const [starHeightMultiplier, setStarHeightMutliplier] = useState(3)
  const [starAnimationDuration, setStarAnimationDuration] = useState(starSpeed.slow)
  const [rocketMargin, setRocketMargin] = useState(60)
```

The function that changes multiplier variable

```
function startCrash() {
    let timeOut = 500;
    const crashEnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1000 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    timeOut = 300
    for (let i = 101; i < crashEnd; i++) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setMultiplier(i/100)
      }, timeOut)
      timeOut += 300;
    }
```

And this is what my component returns

```
<>
        <div className={styles.crashGambleWrapper}>
         <BetMenu money={money} startCrash={startCrash}></BetMenu>

          <h2 className={styles.betMultiplierNum}>{multiplier.toFixed(2)}x</h2>
          <div className={styles.rocketGameWrapper}>
              <div className={styles.rocketWrapper}>
              <h1>CRASH GAMBLE</h1>
              
            <div className={styles.rocketDiv}>
                      <StarAnimation starAnimationDuration={starAnimationDuration} starHeightMultiplier={starHeightMultiplier}></StarAnimation>
                      <div className={styles.rocket} style={{marginTop: `${rocketMargin}vh`, animationDuration: '1s'}}>
                          <img src={rocket}></img>
                      </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            
          </div>
        </div>


    </>
```

This is the component that re-rerenders when it shouldn't

```
<StarAnimation starAnimationDuration={starAnimationDuration} starHeightMultiplier={starHeightMultiplier}></StarAnimation>
```

<StarAnimation>:

```
<>
    {[...Array(40).keys()].map(() => {
        let x = Math.floor(Math.random() * window.innerWidth*0.73)
        let h = Math.random() * starHeightMultiplier;
        let duration = Math.random() * 0.9 + starAnimationDuration;
        return <i style={{
            left: `${x}px`,
            width: `1px`,
            top: '1px',
            height: `${h}px`,
            animationDuration: `${duration}s`
        }}></i>
    })}
  </>
```

How can I stop it from re-rendering everytime I update multiplier var?

Comment: export default React.memo(StarAnimation), https://react.dev/reference/react/memo

Comment: Thank you so much! Would you also know a way of re-rendering them more smoothly when changing the speed. Thank you in advice <3